# Search Query to Exclude Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, search-query

I have a search query that I found off the internet that I want to modify. This code snippet below returns me all the SharePoint lists I currently have access to.

```
(contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web) AND NOT WebTemplate:SPSPERS AND NOT WebTemplate:App AND NOT WebTemplate:AppCatalog AND NOT WebTemplate:PolicyCtr AND NOT WebTemplate:POINTPUBLISHINGHUB AND NOT WebTemplate:POINTPUBLISHINGTOPIC AND NOT WebTemplate:EDISC AND NOT */sites/app_* AND NOT *-my/* AND NOT */contentTypeHub AND NOT *-public*
```

This returns me the correct information but I want to make it stronger by excluding me from a generic user group. Is there a way to adjust this to filter out results where `GROUP NAME <> "ALL EMPLOYEES"`?

Answer (score 0):

User groups do not return in search results when using search query, and they do not have a property to be excluded.

You can use related keywords (plain texts) as you are returning sites using this query, for example:

```
… AND NOT {GroupName/Alias}
```

If you want to exclude all users, use

```
-ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

Or specific users:

```
-AccountName:{UserName}
```